# Python Daemon: ValueError: I/O operation on closed file

Tags: python, python-daemon

I'm trying to use [DaemonContext](https://pypi.org/project/python-daemon/) as follows:

```py
    with DaemonContext(
        working_directory=WORKDIR,
        umask=0o002,
        pidfile=pidfile.TimeoutPIDLockFile(PIDFILE),
    ):
        main()
```

I get the error `ValueError: I/O operation on closed file`. It's unclear if this has to do with the pidfile, stdout/stderr, or something I'm doing inside `main()`. This is running inside a Docker container.

Here's my stack trace. Grateful for any insights.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
    pidfile=pidfile.TimeoutPIDLockFile("/tmp/cwmetrics.pid"),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/daemon/daemon.py", line 272, in __init__
    detach_process = is_detach_process_context_required()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/daemon/daemon.py", line 819, in is_detach_process_context_required
    if is_process_started_by_init() or is_process_started_by_superserver():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/daemon/daemon.py", line 795, in is_process_started_by_superserver
    stdin_fd = sys.__stdin__.fileno()
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file
```

I did report it over here as well: https://pagure.io/python-daemon/issue/64 I'm just unclear if it's an issue with the library or my usage of it.

Comment: Sounds like a bug report rather, or?

Comment: I did report it over here as well: https://pagure.io/python-daemon/issue/64

I'm just unclear if it's an issue with the library or my usage of it.

Comment: Put that info into the question!

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to detach (daemonize) process, but still want to preserve access to default stdin/stdout - but your detached process will not have files to write to. You should create some files, which would be used as stdin/stdout and point to them in arguments.

DaemonContext closes all opened streams on entering context. If you redirects your stdin/stdout somewhere in your code, you may avoid closing them with argument
`files_preserve=[...]`, where you should put those files in the list.

Comment: I get the same behavior if I comment out the two lines setting stdout/stderr. What else can I try?

Comment: try adding `files_preserve=[sys.stdin, sys.stdout]` argument to the DaemonContext

Comment: nope, same error — i'll try the output file tactic next

Comment: okay so I did `output = open(LOGFILE, "w+")` and set stdout/stderr to that file. I also set `files_preserve=[output]` and still got the same error.

Comment: you may try also moving pidfile outside DaemonContext: `pidfile = PIDLockFile(pid_path, timeout=1.0)` and call it with arguments: `with DaemonContext(pidfile=pidfile, ...)`

Comment: Nope, same error.